# Stackdriver agent can't find collectd endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm installing the stackdriver agent on a GCE instance and it's giving me the error:

> $ sudo /opt/stackdriver/stack-config --write-gcm

```
Checking platform...
Using Cloud Monitoring API
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match stackdriver-extractor Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match stackdriver-extractor Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
Disabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/stackdriver-extractor ...
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/stackdriver-extractor ...
  /etc/rc0.d/K20stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc1.d/K20stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc2.d/K80stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc3.d/K80stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc4.d/K80stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc5.d/K80stackdriver-extractor
  /etc/rc6.d/K20stackdriver-extractor
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/stackdriver-extractor ...
 /etc/rc0.d/K20stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc1.d/K20stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc6.d/K20stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc2.d/K80stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc3.d/K80stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc4.d/K80stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
 /etc/rc5.d/K80stackdriver-extractor -> ../init.d/stackdriver-extractor
Restarting services
 * Restarting Stackdriver metrics collection agent stackdriver-agent
Unable to determine collectd endpoint!
 * not starting, configuration error
...fail!
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem, we are using a stackdriver account and that collects the metrics from several GCP projects, so I needed to use an API key (--api-key option) for that account instead of doing the default GCM install (--write-gcm option).